# backing up and restoring the eMMC

Tags: google-coral

What would be the procedure to backup the onboard eMMC from the SD card image of the google coral dev board?
Similarly, what procedure should we follow to restore the image to the emmc drive onboard?

Answer (score 4):

> backup the onboard eMMC from the SD card image

The Mendel OS image isn't installed on the sdcard so do you mean just backing up the emmc so that you can put it on another board? If so, here is the proceedure:

In order to backup emmc, you'll first need to mount your dev board as a USB device on your linux host machine. You do this, by connecting to your board via serial console and put it in u-boot mode (just boot the board up and press any keys within the first 3 seconds), make sure the USB-C cable is also connected. In u-boot prompt, enters:

```
U-Boot# ums 0 mmc 0
```

This will mount the dev board on your host machine as a USB device. Locate that device using the "fdisk -l" command. Then you can dd the bytes from that disk into an img file:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/path-to-dev-board of=./backup.img bs=4M status=progress
```

Be very careful that you are copying from the correct path, or else you'll copy from the wrong device. Next you can dd this backup image to any other board by first mounting a new board on your host machine and then locate the board with fdisk (same steps as above). Then you can dd the backup image to your board by reversing the dd command:

```
$ sudo dd if=./backup.img of=/dev/path-to-dev-board bs=4M status=progress
```

Be very careful with the out file path this time, because you can replace the wrong drive with the bytes from backup.img (that would be irreversible).

Comment: Awesome, I will try this later and update. Thank you for your KIND instructions.

Comment: value for status shold be `progress`, not `progess`. Answer can not be edited because an edit should be at least 6 chars.

Comment: Could you clarify how to put it into u-boot mode? My understanding is that I first connect the serial console USB cable, then plug in the USB-C power cable which will start booting the board, then press a key on a keyboard connected to the coral, then run `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` to connect to serial console and it should be at the u-boot prompt? Is this correct?

Comment: I figured out what I needed to do: Power on the board and connect to serial console. Once it boots then press the reset button on the dev board, and immediately press a key in the serial console to get the uboot prompt

Comment: How long should I wait for the device to appear? After running `ums 0 mmc 0` at the u-boot prompt it printed `configured usb switch for ufp` then had a loading animation that did not stop (tried for 30+ minutes). The device never showed up under fdisk during that time

Comment: I answered to your question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72628758/7396613). Make sure to have the 3 cables connected, Power, OTG and serial cable. @brad

Comment: Would `cat` work instead of `dd`? I have read ([source1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days), [source2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250025/is-dd-really-necessary-to-clone-a-disk?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and a big etc more sources,  that it can be used instead of `dd`, and it is faster. But I have only seen it with literal partition inputs, and not a `.img` input.

Comment: Would this process work for cloning the drive of one coral to a brand new coral?

Comment: @brad yes it works but keep in mind this also writes system settings and I think the MAC addr of the old board to the new one, iirc

Comment: Thanks Nam, it seems to be working as you said. One question, how can I permanently change the wlan0 mac address after cloning? I see the Ethernet address can be changed as a uboot environment variable, but I do not see one for wlan. I have been unsuccessful with reconnecting to wifi if I use something like macchanger